# how to assign global NSInteger object in derived class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates

```
//AppDelegate.h
AppDelegate NSInteger myInt;
@property (readwrite, assign) NSInteger myInt;

//AppDelegate.m
@synthesize myInt;


//MyClass.h

AppDelegate *objAppDelegate;

//MyClass.m

objAppDelegate =  (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

When I try to assign a value to myInt like

```
objAppDelegate.myInt=(NSInteger *)0; // <--- this gives warning: something like incompatible pointer to integer conversion like that
```

So, how can I assign this variable?

Comment: Thanks for answers everyone. If I want to check if myInt is assigned or not else assign to 0. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objAppDelegate.myInt = (NSInteger)0;`

OR

`objAppDelegate.myInt = 0;`

You should assign to an NSInteger without a pointer.

Comment: @Asterisx22 when I compare like  objAppDelegate.myInt == NULL ---- it gives warning: Comparison between pointer and integer (*NSInteger' (aka 'int) and 'void *'))

Comment: You cannot compare `NSInteger` to `NULL`, because it's not a class object. Instead, compare like `objAppDelegate.myInte == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

`NSInteger` is not a class type. And you are trying to use its variable as a pointer. It will work when you change code to `objAppDelegate.myInt = 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

NSInteger is not an object, it's a typedef.

```
objAppDelegate.myInt=0;
```

should do it.